# How to implement search view autocomplete in actionbar using http request?

Tags: android, search, autocomplete

I've added [search view](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html) widget to my action bar and would like to handle autocomplete feature. After writing more then 3 letters it should fulfill http request to my web API which will return json result and should show search widget suggestions.
But in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html) is observed the case with content providers. How can I organize autocomplete feature?

Added search view in menu xml file:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:title="Search"
    [namespace]:showAsAction="always"
    [namespace]:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

Associates searchable configuration with the SearchView:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Added searchable configuration:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.my.domain.searchable_activity" />
```

And ultimately added empty responsible activity.

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: Need to find solution with http request.

Comment: please show what have you done till now ??

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't do this with `setSearchableInfo()` and a search configuration.

The problem is that `SearchView` needs a `CursorAdapter` and you are retrieving data from the server, not the database.

However, I have done something like this before with these steps:

- Set up your `SearchView` to use a `CursorAdapter`;

  ```
      searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(
              context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, 
              new String[] { SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1 }, 
              new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }));
  ```
- Create an `AsyncTask` to read the JSON data from your server and create a `MatrixCursor` from the data:

  ```
  public class FetchSearchTermSuggestionsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Cursor> {

      private static final String[] sAutocompleteColNames = new String[] { 
              BaseColumns._ID,                         // necessary for adapter
              SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1      // the full search term
      };

      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(String... params) {

          MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(sAutocompleteColNames);

          // get your search terms from the server here, ex:
          JSONArray terms = remoteService.getTerms(params[0]);

          // parse your search terms into the MatrixCursor
          for (int index = 0; index < terms.length(); index++) {
              String term = terms.getString(index);

              Object[] row = new Object[] { index, term };
              cursor.addRow(row);
          }

          return cursor;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
          searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().changeCursor(result);
      }

  }
  ```
- Set an `OnQueryTextListener` to kick off your remote server task or start your search activity:

  ```
      searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

          @Override
          public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

              if (query.length() >= SEARCH_QUERY_THRESHOLD) {
                  new FetchSearchTermSuggestionsTask().execute(query);
              } else {
                  searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().changeCursor(null);
              }

              return true;
          }

          @Override
          public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

              // if user presses enter, do default search, ex:
              if (query.length() >= SEARCH_QUERY_THRESHOLD) {

                  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchableActivity.class);
                  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
                  intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
                  startActivity(intent);

                  searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().changeCursor(null);
                  return true;
              }
          }
      });
  ```
- Set an `OnSuggestionListener` on the `SearchView` to execute your search:

  ```
      searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new OnSuggestionListener() {

          @Override
          public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {

              Cursor cursor = (Cursor) searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getItem(position);
              String term = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1));
              cursor.close();

              Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchableActivity.class);
              intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
              intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, term);
              startActivity(intent);

              return true;
          }

          @Override
          public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {

              return onSuggestionSelect(position);
          }
      });
  ```

Comment: Thanks, works for me. In my case the suggestion line represents an user icon, name, location and image button. What type of CursorAdapter you can offer?

Comment: In which case your `MatrixCursor` would have 5 fields: the `_id` field, the icon field, the name field, the location field, and the image field.  `SimpleCursorAdapter` probably won't be adequate for the icon and image, so you would have to subclass `CursorAdapter` and override `newView()` to inflate a custom layout and `bindView()` to map the cursor data to your layout widgets. A note about `bindView()`:  It is passed a `Cursor` but no position.  That's because the cursor is already positioned on the correct record; all you have to do is grab the current field values.

Comment: Awesome response; just a quick fix: in the call to changeCursor in onPostExecute, the argument should be `result` not `cursor`

Comment: I just did that to see if anyone was paying attention.  :)  Fixed, thx